# Wordpress - add add_rewrite_rule with variable number of arguments

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I want to create add_rewrite_rule for a variable number of arguments. 
E.g. this add_rewrite_rule should work for any of these link type:

```
/workouts/filter/red/round/solid/
/workouts/filter/red/round/
/workouts/filter/red/
```

This is what I have for now but is working for exactly 4 arguments:

```
add_rewrite_rule(

'^workouts/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$', 
'index.php?page_id=763&type=$matches[1]&var1=$matches[2]&var2=$matches[3]&var3=$matches[4]', 'top');
```

Let me know if there is a solution at this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: The only solution that I found was to replace the regular expression to `^workouts/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$` so this allow me to create as many arguments I want: `/workouts/filter/red/round/solid/.../.../../.../`